# Center object in div with Animation

Tags: html, css

Trying to set an animation to an object but can only get it working when I target the outer div. Doesn't seem to work when I target the object

```
.more {
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    bottom: 4rem;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center; 
    background: red;
    opacity: .5;
}

.more1 {    
    -webkit-transition: bottom;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 500ms;

}

.more1:hover {
    -webkit-transition: bottom;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-in;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 500ms;
    bottom: 2rem;
}
```

This is what I thought would work: 
http://jsfiddle.net/mexicanbandit/a7k4uskm/9/

Closest I have got **but only want it to target the object** and not the div with the object being centered
http://jsfiddle.net/mexicanbandit/a7k4uskm/10/

Thanks, any help would be good

Comment: Not everyone got webkit browser to test it... You should always remember about CSS3 transition without of any prefix... ;). -moz and -o should be nice too :).

Comment: My bad, it just what I'm using and just did a quick copy+paste job from my work. Fixed it now :)